# In your Understanding what is the scope of a Toolsmith in Software Development?

Tags: development-environment, clearcase

I've been asked to maintain a few of our software development tools; Clearcase (Views, Streams, Triggers), JIRA, Enterprise Architect and various document based repositories, Confluence, doku Wiki etc..

But as I wonder where does the line is when it comes to the "best practices" and cleanup efforts to make the most of these tools for development teams. 
for an SysAdmin perspective it's quite easy; Make sure u maintain the application, network and backup system. but when it's development support and in the term used "Tool's Smith" I believe is half way between a lead developer and system administrator.

Comment: A "toolsmith" in the original idea, which comes from The Mythical Man Month, was not someone who maintained existing tools (because there weren't many), but who wrote new ones for the programming team. It was (and I suppose is) a subservient & not really necessary role

Comment: Depends on how you look at it, in one way you save developers time and in other words it just makes them lazy, i guess. However your right I feel pulled back because of the idea of this roll. However in a large org I think one thing is requires is one consistently meeting with various departments to see that the various tools are used to the greater extent of there features. For example Clearcase can be powerful but yes a pain if you don't understand it's purpose fully.

Comment: @Neil so you're saying Rico Mariani, Eric Lippert and co. are subservient to .net developers, because they work on the tools? Traditionally toolsmiths were the best craftsmen in the workshop, as if your lathe is wonky everything made by it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I would view this as someone in charge of proposing a framework enabling the developer to not see those tools, but only the process he/she needs to follow:

- declare a new task (behind the scene: open a JIRA ticket)
- associate to a project (UCM snasphot view to a Stream, download the code)
- document the task (new page in the wiki)
- ...

The administration of those tools is still there, but a bit of development is needed to help the users (developers) in their daily process without them having constantly to think about the specificities of each tools.

Answer (score 1):

If they wanted you to be a lead developer, they wouldn't have given you a title of "Tool Smith".  I would view it as a specialized system administrator, more more to the point, application administrator.  You might have some additional development responsibilities but being in charge of maintaining the tools probably doesn't confer any responsibility over how those tools are used.

Just my $0.02.